# Spring DSL editing and saving in code - is it possible?

Tags: java, spring, grails, dsl

I need to configure spring beans in grails dynamicly and save configuration in project so that after server restarting changed configuration do not lose.

Is it possible to do it by using spring DSL or another way? Spring XML is not suitable for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to register beans to applicationContext dynamically after app has started.

You can do it with code like this:

```
def grailsApplication 
... 
def beanDef = new GenericBeanDefinition(beanClass: MyBean, 
  autowireMode:AbstractBeanDefinition.AUTOWIRE_BY_NAME) 

String beanName = '...' 

grailsApplication.mainContext.registerBeanDefinition beanName, beanDef
```

You can also specify the bean scope (e.g. if it's a prototype bean) and set other properties in the GenericBeanDefinition before registering it.

Source http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Apache-Commons-IO-2-0-1-td3307531.html#a3307950